# Why user accounts do "not have permission to run this task"?

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, scheduled-tasks, xml

I am creating a Scheduled task configured via PowerShell using the XML:

```
$LogonTask_xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>$(get-date -Format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.00000)</Date>
    <Author>Interactive</Author>
    <Description>$LogonDescription</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Delay>PT1H</Delay>
      <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT4H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <GroupId>S-1-5-32-545</GroupId>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT4H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>$VBScriptPath</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
"@
```

I want all users to run within their own context -- but not modify -- and when they test it, they keep encountering "The user account does not have permission to run this task."

As you can see, the task runs as the `Users` group, and is allowed to start on demand.  The task works fine if I run it as an administrator.  The "users" group can see this particular task and has read & execute rights to the task file (in c:\Windows\System32\Tasks), and users can create other tasks and run them.  I would swear that this used to work.

When I created another task and manipulated the ACL to exactly match the "troublesome" task, the second task still runs at a user's request without a problem.

There must be something else about some tasks that can prevent unprivileged users from running them, but I cannot figure out what it might be.  Help!

Comment: Sharing screenshots or XML of how you configured the task might help

Comment: When the user account is logged onto the machine that they run this scheduled task, what happens if while logged on your execute `$VBScriptPath`? The accounts will need to have execute to whatever the `$VBScriptPath` variable points to at execution time so that could be the issue so check this just in case. You might also be sure to check `Run whether user is logged on or not` and `Run with Highest privileges` to see if that makes any difference. Test cmd.exe access too plus executing the job via `schtasks` while signed onto the machine.

Comment: An unprivileged user can manually run the `$VBScriptPath`.  The `Run with Highest privileges` doesn't make any difference.  I can't tick on the `Run whether user is logged on or not` which I suspect is because it doesn't run under a single user account.  It runs under the `Users` local group so that it is for all users.  Running it via `schtasks /run /i /tn <taskname>` returns `ERROR: Access is denied.`  A test task to open Notepad with identical ACL runs without a problem every way I try.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles on this in the future, here is the answer...

At some point, Microsoft stopped using the task files in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` to control security on Scheduled Tasks.  Claims are that it happened with Win10, but it can't have been early versions of Win10 because my problem didn't occur until more recent releases.

Nevertheless, the ability to run scheduled tasks is now controlled through registry settings under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree`, but those keys are protected from "normal" admins.  I found [code to add the permissions here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b9b7ac3-41cd-419e-ac25-c15c45766c8e/scheduled-task-that-any-user-can-run), and cleaned it up into [something I will be using to allow a single task to be run by any user](https://github.com/teknowledgist/TeknowTools/tree/master/Unlock-ScheduledTask).

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: The scripts do fix this problem when run as admin, but strangely fail when run as SYSTEM even though the change is ultimately done in the SYSTEM context.