# Registry key in HKLM "invisible" to SYSTEM?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, scheduled-tasks, acl

I'm trying [to allow all users to execute a scheduled task](https://superuser.com/questions/1636318/why-user-accounts-do-not-have-permission-to-run-this-task).  The script I [found](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b9b7ac3-41cd-419e-ac25-c15c45766c8e/scheduled-task-that-any-user-can-run)/[adjusted](https://github.com/teknowledgist/TeknowTools/tree/master/Unlock-ScheduledTask) works fine when run as an admin, but fails when run as SYSTEM (i.e. as a startup or SCCM script).

Walking through the code as the SYSTEM account, I discovered that the SYSTEM account cannot see 95% of the child items under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree`.  Whether I use PowerShell or open Regedit directly as the SYSTEM account, there is (almost) nothing there.  However, a normal admin can see dozens of subkeys and all their properties.

The really odd thing is that the solution for the original problem *requires* a task run as the SYSTEM account that modifies one of the "hidden/protected" sub keys.  It works, but only as an admin.  I need to be able to see/read the keys -- as SYSTEM.

How can the SYSTEM account not be able to see registry keys in HKLM?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the reserved account SYSTEM, which anyway isn't a real account.

When creating the task,
use "Change user or group" to set the user account to just "users", by typing
`users` into the object-name field and clicking "Check Names", then OK.

Set also "Run only when user is logged on".

This way all users will be able to manually run the task.

---

*Note for the latest versions of Windows 10:*

Doing `schtasks /run` now requires administrator permissions,
so is no longer possible for a non-admin user.
In the latest versions of Windows, Microsoft has now closed up the
loophole by which a non-admin user could launch an admin task
via the Task Scheduler,
so this method that has worked for so many years is now no longer possible.

An alternative solution that still works is the utility
[RunAsSpc](https://robotronic.de/runasspcen.html),
free for private use, described as:

> Run application as another user or start program as administrator from a limited account like the command `runas`, but without to enter login information on each start.

Comment: That doesn't work. Try it using an admin account.  Unprivileged users can see the task, but not run it.  See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6b9b7ac3-41cd-419e-ac25-c15c45766c8e/scheduled-task-that-any-user-can-run) or my post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1636318/why-user-accounts-do-not-have-permission-to-run-this-task) for evidence.

Comment: I think I see: You're trying to workaround `schtasks` now requiring Admin permission, and the old SYSTEM trick is no longer working. I can suggest as solution [RunAsSpc](https://robotronic.de/runasspcen.html), free for private use, which will allow you to do what you ask for.

Comment: Nope.  Originally, I had a startup script (which run as SYSTEM) that was creating a scheduled task via XML and PowerShell to be run at all user logins. That worked in Win7 and early Win10, but now the protected registry key sets permissions to tasks, and Admin users can't change it.

Comment: Yes, Microsoft has closed up the loophole by which a non-admin user could launch an admin task. This no longer works, so another solution is required. I tested RunAsSpc and it works in the latest Windows 10, if it's useful to you.

Comment: As usual, Microsoft went too far.  In my case, this is a task created (and potentially changed) by admins that non-admin users need to run **within their own context**.  It doesn't do any "admin-y" things, but it is a read-only task for unprivileged users with read-only settings, triggers, and actions.  The question isn't about changing the permissions to allow unprivileged users from running it, but reading the existing permissions during startup and/or SCCM deployment (i.e. as SYSTEM).  The registry key is hidden from SYSTEM.

Comment: I would advise against changing permissions on sensitive registry entries. We all need to live with the new Windows and cannot go back.